# Typescript - Craft Json object from array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

This question probably will be down-voted, but just asking for my knowledge...

What I have now:

```
data = {COLUMN1: "DATA1", COLUMN2: "DATA2", COLUMN3: "DATA3", ..., COLUMNn: "DATAn"};

keyColumns = ["COLUMN2", "COLUMN5", "COLUMN9"];

keyValueMap = {};
```

What I want to get:

```
keyValueMap = {COLUMN2: "DATA2", COLUMN5: "DATA5", COLUMN9: "DATA9"};
```

What I have tried:

```
if (keyColumns.length > 0)
    {
      keyColumns.forEach(a => {
        keyvaluemap[a] = data[a];

      });
    };
```

I know that I cannot do keyvaluemap[a] = data[a], because keyvaluemap is just an object. How can I craft it so that it gets all value pairs as I wanted? The list of values in keyColumns cannot be known until runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of Arrays:

```js
let data = {COLUMN1: "DATA1", COLUMN2: "DATA2", COLUMN3: "DATA3", COLUMN4: "DATA4",COLUMN5: "DATA5", COLUMN9: "DATA9"},
    keyColumns = ["COLUMN2", "COLUMN5", "COLUMN9"];

let reducer = (obj, arr) => arr.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = obj[c], a), {});

console.log(reducer(data, keyColumns));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
const result = keyColumns.reduce((acc, cur) => !!data[cur] ? ({...acc, [cur]: data[cur]}) : acc;
}, {});
```